# What is the Difference between build generated for development and for production in sencha

Tags: extjs, build, difference

I am new to sencha and working on build process. Will you please help me the difference ? Cause while building development build in sencha files are not getting copied properly, so can not able to find the difference.

Thanks.

Comment: How you are firing build for both of them.Specify them.

Comment: For production :
    -  sencha app build classic production

and  For development 
     -  sencha app build classic development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For production build Sencha:

- use minified sources without comments
- merge separate js files into app.js

In development build you have unpacked resources and files in case you need to debug or look through them.